# Can't see the relink documents view due to 5000+ limit

Tags: sharepoint-online, limitations

I've managed to figure out how to display the 5000+ items in my form library in other views but can't do it with the Relink documents view as it just shows me the 5000+ limit warning. I can't modify view as it's not a normal view and doesn't show as an option when clicking modify view.
Any ideas?

Regards,
C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set indexes on the columns in the library an use those columns in your filter criteria and be sure you don't end up with the filtered result above the 5000 items.